# about legend tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following legend the text is many characters (long Question) ..What I want is that only first 10 characters of the question be displayed and then dots..something like :-

What is asp.net? What do yo...

How do I do this?

```
<fieldset style="padding: 10px;">                         
    <legend style="padding: 5px;">
    <b>     
        Question:&nbsp; &nbsp;     
        <%#Eval("Question")%>     
    </b>
    </legend>                      
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Learn how to format code and markup properly and start do it! Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code behind where you expose the `Question` property, I'd also expose a `TruncatedQuestion` like so:

```
public string TruncatedQuestion
{
    get
    {
         if (Question.Length > 10)
             return Question.Substring(0,10) + "...";
         else
             return Question;
    }
}
```

Then replace `<%#Eval("Question")%>` in your code with `<%#Eval("TruncatedQuestion")%>`

Comment: where do I need to define this TruncatedQuestion string in my code ? where exactly?

Comment: Where is the Question currently defined? Next to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this via CSS with some proper markup:

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Question: <% #Eval("Question") %></legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset
{
    padding: 10px;
}

legend
{
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`text-overflow:`[`ellipsis`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) will work in IE7, Safari and Mozilla.

Comment: its giving me this error "Validation (CSS 2.0): 'text-overflow' is not a known CSS property name."

Comment: That's because it's a CSS 3.0 value and Visual Studio's support for CSS is pretty sub-par. It's safe to ignore the warnings and see for yourself what the browser produces. At worse, it will ignore it and not add the ellipsis for you.